# Area of a crossed diagonal quadrilateral

Tags: determinant, analytic-geometry, area

If four coordinates of vertices are given, the area of the first convex quadrilateral is expressed in known standard matrix form.

How is the net (positive and negative sum ) area expressed for the second one if the diagonals are cross-connected ?

By interchanging columns/rows... only the sign of the determinant changes.

[image]